# Google App Engine Remote Api Import Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I connected to my app using remote_api. When I try to import my models using this

```
from models import SimpleCounterShard
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named models
```

I tried searching for solutions and it seems something to do with PYTHONPATH. Can someone tell me how to fix this ? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added the application directory to my system path and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to remote_api provides you with access to your production data, but not to your python modules. Your source code must be available on your local machine to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do have my source code in my local machine and my cwd is same as my application directory

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for OSX.
I simply append the Python libs from the AppEngine Python SDK.
Make sure that your app.yaml contains the magic sentence.

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on

import sys
import glob

sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine')
for l in glob.glob("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/*"):
    sys.path.append(l)

import getpass
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
# import your app-specific libraries here.

def auth_func():
  return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))
  # or hardcode it; remember you MUST use application passwords.
  # https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
  # return ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,
                               '______.appspot.com')

# do your stuff here.
```